# Can someone point me to a good, up-to-date review article on the effectiveness of vaccines against the omicron variant of the coronavirus?

Tags: covid-19, vaccination, coronavirus

I would like to learn about the effectiveness of vaccines against the omicron variant of the coronavirus.  I believe a review article from a scientific journal would have the best information.  I would prefer a review article over a paper about an individual study, since a review would summarize what is known from various studies.  I was not trained in biology or medicine, but I do have a PhD in a scientific field (physics).  Given that I am a scientist, I believe I should be able to generally understand an article in a scientific journal.  I have searched Google Scholar.  However, since neither biology nor medicine is my area of expertise, I am having trouble deciding which articles are authoritative.

I am looking for a review which is considered authoritative by doctors and biologists, and I would appreciate someone pointing me to such an article.  I would prefer a review which was published relatively recently in a journal with a high impact factor, and which has a fairly high number of citations.  However, I understand that the more recent an article is, the fewer citations it can be expected to have.

I am not trying to decide whether to get vaccinated; I am fully vaccinated, and I received my booster shot.  I simply want to find out how well vaccines protect against infection and serious illness from the omicron variant.

Thank you.

Comment: HI Casper, welcome to Medical Sciences. I have some feedback that is my personal opinion. First, this question is interesting and important (and it doesn't seem like we've addressed this one in a while). However, it reads like a lot of requirements about what exactly *you* want. I think it would be better if a lot of your personal details were not included. Also, it doesn't include any prior research. What did you find that wasn't up to standard? I can make some attempts at an edit if you're open to it.

Comment: Omicron is only 4 months old, so I‘m not sure if there any reviews in high IF journals yet because the peer-review process is likely to take a month or more, and there needs to be time for primary studies to be conducted as well.

Comment: A PubMed search with these keywords „ ((Omicron) AND (Review[Publication Type])) AND (vaccine[Title/Abstract])“ did not yield any good results. I think a better option would be to look at primary articles…

Comment: @IanCampbell Thank you for the suggestions.  I agree that I probably put too many requirements into my question.  Narusan sent me a link to a paper on a good study.  That was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that there are any reviews available yet - the first high quality studies regarding vaccination efficacy against Omicron have just recently been published. A PubMed search with the keywords *((Omicron) AND (Review[Publication Type])) AND (vaccine[Title/Abstract])* did not give meaningful results yet.

A good case-control study is [this study in the New England Journal of Medicine](https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMoa2119451), published 11 days ago. A case-control study is still fairly low on the quality pyramid of evidence based medical research, but there has simply not yet enough time passed for good experimental studies:

[image]

There are also [quite](https://www.thelancet.com/journals/lancet/article/PIIS0140-6736(22)00092-7/fulltext) a [few](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0092867421014963?casa_token=LMjvS4r4d68AAAAA:-3vl5kxVE8AWTppMXpLYCstJb6ImnoSUHLHpb8zLDVTJ4_cDKtKM-imFMNeTWM3sY9bVIbRF) good articles on virus neutralisation in vitro, which is only a proxy for vaccine efficacy in vivo.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the article.  That is helpful.